# Robot Framework - HtmlWriter omitting jquery?

Tags: robotframework

Some time ago, the Robot Framework output files; log.html and report.html, stopped being view-able within a browser. A blank white screen appeared and the browser console threw an "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comparing an older working log.html to a current non-working log, the broken version is missing code from the following 3 files:

1. jsxcompressor.min.js
2. jquery.min.js
3. jquery.tablesorter.min.js

Each is a single enormous function call which is why they are omitted.

Copying and pasting them into the non-working html file allows it to open with all of its actual result data.

I haven't made any modifications to the robot files but is it possible something happened to mess with the HtmlWriter? Is anyone familiar with that process and knows where that code gets injected into the log.html? I have examined all of the .js, .py files and tried to trace the different modules but was not able to understand it.

**EDIT:** I do not think it is related, but someone may find this useful for assisting as well.
We use a customized jybot.bat to integrate Sikuli and Robot framework. The modified batch file is below. This has not changed from when the output was working 2 months ago.

```
@echo on
setlocal
set ROBOT_HOME=%~dp0
set JYTHON_HOME=%ROBOT_HOME%
set SIKULIX_HOME=%ROBOT_HOME%
REM echo %CLASSPATH%

set CLASSPATH=%SIKULIX_HOME%sikulixapi.jar;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\jython2.7.0\bin\;C:\jython2.7.0\lib\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\

REM;%CLASSPATH%
set JYTHONPATH=%SIKULIX_HOME%sikulixapi.jar\Lib

javaw -cp %JYTHON_HOME%jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar;% org.python.util.jython ^
    %ROBOT_HOME%robot\run.py ^
    --pythonpath=%ROBOT_HOME%program.sikuli ^
%*
endlocal
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What interpreter are you using? What Robot Framework version? (As you said some time ago) Etc..

Comment: A customized jython jybot.bat with Robot 3.0

Comment: have you submitted a bug report to the robot framework maintainers? I'm using 2.9.1 and the logs work perfectly fine in a browser.

Comment: Will do. Didn't want to submit something that I had not vetted wasn't a simple error on my part. I may also download the 2.9.1 files and run a diff against the 3.0 version on the files that generate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This was an environment specific issue. For anyone with similar problems in the future, a complication in our deployment was stripping the javascript files when retrieving them from source control. The Robot HTMLWriter was working correctly but was writing in empty values from the stripped files.